# How to get the path of an internal folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I have a project in WinForms C# that I created an internal folder `reports` to add my RDLC reports, its works fine when I'm developing, the problem is when I create the `Setup` to install application using `InstallShield Limited Edition` because after install the application I try execute the report and thrown an exception and not show its.

Developing I think its works because the executable is created in `Debug\bin` and I get does path using `@..\..\reports\MyReport.rdlc` but after create the `Setup` and install the application this folder `reports` not exist.

How do I solve this ?

**To open the Report I do.**

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"..\..\reports\RelContasPagar.rdlc";
```

**Exception**

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: Ocorreu um erro durante o processamento de relatórios local. ---> System.ApplicationException: A definição do relatório 'RelFluxoCaixa' não foi especificada ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\reports\RelFluxoCaixa.rdlc'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore.GetReportDefinition(PreviewItemContext itemContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore.GetReportDefinition(PreviewItemContext itemContext)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at ControleDeVendas.reports.ViewReport.geraRelFluxoCaixa()
   at ControleDeVendas.reports.ViewReport.executeTipoRelatorio()
   at ControleDeVendas.reports.ViewReport.ViewReport_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ControleDeVendas
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Iguana%20Sistemas/Controle%20de%20Vendas/ControleDeVendas.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
NHibernate
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.4000
    Win32 Version: 4.0.4.4000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Iguana%20Sistemas/Controle%20de%20Vendas/NHibernate.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
FluentNHibernate
    Assembly Version: 2.0.3.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.3.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Iguana%20Sistemas/Controle%20de%20Vendas/FluentNHibernate.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.GeneratedCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 6.9.8.0
    Win32 Version: 6.9.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MySql.Data/v4.0_6.9.8.0__c5687fc88969c44d/MySql.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms/11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources/11.0.0.0_pt_89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common/11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.resources
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.resources/11.0.0.0_pt_89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

**Internal folder**

[image]

Comment: How are the report files packed in your Installation project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on the `Build Action` property of those `rdlc` files in your project:

- *Build Action* is *Embedded Resource*

  If the `Build Action` is `Embedded Resource`, then you don't need to use file path. Those reports have been embedded in your executable file and you can use them this way:

  ```
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Sample.Reports.Report1.rdlc";
  ```

  It's the default behavior when you add report to your project. Visual Studio sets the build action as embedded resource.
- *Build Action* is *Content* And *Copy To Output Directory* is *Copy Always*

  If the `Build Action` id `Content` and `Copy To Output Directory` is `Copy Always` then your file will be find under the bin folder of your project under the same folder name which the have in the the solution. So you can find them this way:

  ```
  var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Reports", "Report1.rdlc");
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = path;
  ```

**Note**

- In the first option in `Sample.Reports.Report1.rdlc`, `Sample` is the namespace, `Reports` is the folder name and `Report1.rdlc` is the report name.
- If you used the second option, make sure your setup maker tool copies those files in the output directory under `\Reports` folder.

Comment: that's it. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Couple of days before I was facing the same issue in Windows Store App, I just replaced back slash i.e. "\" with forward slash i.e. "/". 
Example:-

```
@../../reports/MyReport.rdlc
```

As far I researched on it in certain cases backslash is used for linux.

Comment: can you tell me full absolute path of your project directory? i.e. from C:// ... and so on?

Comment: Moreover, you can try by removing "../../" though I'm not sure but in certain cases application i.e. ".Exe" is by default located in root directory.

Comment: after install is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Iguana Sistemas\Controle de Vendas`

Comment: Trying removing " ../../ "

Comment: Those reports are more likely embedded resources, and if not the `@"./reports/report1.rdlc"` is what you need. Also as a better option you can use `System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Reports", "Report1.rdlc")`.

Answer (score 0):

~/reports/MyReport.rdlc

~ will get root

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a Windows Forms project. The question has `WinForms` tag.